# Creating a function to turn a vector of vectors into a list of lists

Tags: racket

I understand how to turn a vector into a list with vector->list but I was wondering if there was a way to create a function in order to do so. For example:

```
(define test-board (vector
                    (vector 1 0 1 0 0 1)
                    (vector 0 0 0 1 0 1)
                    (vector 1 0 0 0 1 1)))
```

I know that I can go line by line and do this:

```
(define test-board (vector->list(vector
                    (vector->list(vector 1 0 1 0 0 1))
                    (vector->list(vector 0 0 0 1 0 1))
                    (vector->list(vector 1 0 0 0 1 1))
                    )
              )
  )
```

But is there a way to create a function to do this without having to go line by line?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
(vector->list
 (vector-map vector->list test-board))
```